# How to insert data in specific table cells?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to build Calendar of Tv Shows episodes. I have the TV shows and which day they air in a database, but I have no idea how to enter the data in a specific cell. For example, if it airs on Wednesday, the show needs to be put in the Wednesday column.

Here is the code in the View. I don't know how to continue.
Should I put ids or something in the thead cells, and then use them to find the right column or is there something easier that I can't think of?

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Monday</td><td>Tuesday</td><td>Wednesday</td><td>Thursday</td><td>Friday</td><td>Saturday</td><td>Sunday</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach(var item in Model){

        <tr></tr>
    }


</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work :

```
@foreach(var item in Model){
    if(item.Day == "Monday")
    {
        <tr><td>@item.Name</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    }
    else if(item.Day == "Thusday")
    {
        <tr><td></td><td>@item.Name</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    }
    @* And so on for everyday of the week *@
}
```

But i guess you are searching for something already implemented by M.V.C, and i can't think of anything that exist for this situation.

Comment: No, no, this was actually what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If your Day is on a DateTime type object you could do something like this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model){
   int dayNumber = item.DayOfWeek.GetHashCode();
   <tr>
       for(int i = 0; i < dayNumber; i++)
       {
           <td></td>
       }
       <td>@item.ShowName</td>
   </tr>
}
```

This only really gets you away from doing the string compare on the day name, but string compares give me the willies.

EDIT:

More elegant:

```
@foreach(var item in Model){
   <tr>
       for(int i = 0; i < item.DayOfWeek.GetHashCode(); i++)
       {
           <td></td>
       }
       <td>@item.ShowName</td>
   </tr>
}
```

Comment: Very good logic, `item.DayOfWeek.GetHashCode()` This is the function I missed to do it. You don't even need the int then

Comment: This is what I was looking for but there is one problem. This creates a new row for every item in the database.. and I need to have one in each day where is necessary. But yeah, this is what I asked, and you helped me for that.